# Excel add-ins in the same ribbon name are not visible

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

[image]

it works on my computer. 1 of the add-ons is not visible on another computer but when i change their names they both work

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a clash somewhere... Do you get any ribbon UI errors?

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in user interface errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors?view=vs-2019) article.